# Data-layout, layers and legends in vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

I have a very simple situation, and I believe my solution is too complicated and there's a good chance I'm missing something. Say I have measures of `time`, positions (x,y,z), angles (roll, pitch, yaw) and speed. I want a simple visualization like I currently have where the speed plot can be used as "brush" to zoom dynamically into the first two graphs.

[image]

A small example of my plot in the vega-editor [can be found here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoHHVhp+ABkqXLAZjEBOAIwB2O6-eXHthwA4lACc2QUE0a1sAJjtHRzEANkc7aIBWV0cUjzslCBw4OGU0Z0o-P3jI52Skx0iUt2SlTBoEOHCbaPKxJQAPCwjLSL8PP2c-FMs-JPi3VyUATzbLZzFK52nXJbs6stdneaQAd0WB0YTB2L9IgZSa7JAALz6bN2n4vyixWsq7OwBfBRMZhgT1sYhGkz8K3iHkijjGsxAwVCx0iiWcjlc0IubmcywRuXyhVQkRKfkxV2hkUGlhSpUazVaqGsyzcCVi7I5cJ6IIGYN8sUGnjEwsc8Xmi1Gnh+ZWiljEN1cZX2RyZNgGdniYm8lkV7mpkXlSkeqCs7WiuOS0TGQzWKX+gMw5hN-VpzhS8Q9TjJTiWe0RITCqqitXiKQSn2mY1haRyeQKaDsJVp3k8rjqwssiTuTRabUiu3K3Odap+S1cYIrmox+YRCyDVzDCXGE3RtI8ypRdjG4zSDjEithOqNIKpPg8lTK-dq5ftIFMjuBxds5UjNzi5ay5aCAeOE4NnVRuoqkVjhLQEkbaYh8rhpTFIBzjOsXYxnyLptsA487mccrJA3vOsInRC4lgmNMajRLoQDmQ4UVcQZ4hpPkI12P1jQ-dFMTSBDLl-ZY5XiWd5ydD9M2WHxIVpLVRWmE9-WRINPxcFYXE8SYnHce8CXjVAJHLdx5WFMQYkzRJ6VzVU6lfP1eiXeo1jldJf0xRUAhgxYrkzG05VhDI0zTDsmK7ZxZVDOxcTdNMUnojDgKQmkMV2LV+2mT5fgAXX+FR9CgQIaBwJo5DQEAAEEAAIIGaHBBDgcKmCQQJwtgRLMHCg46BgcLECYAplAKcLVHUShFBAYgoDkKA1CMUA4FkCrlBoWQyDQUA5NAJBuhoAxNAfOhYpCkBvIAMxoOBBCJPrcxyKqBt65Q2GQJrWpACBxrgKAgvkdAmECBgIGBX5vMwOY8hCgBHBgkFkJp1CaUghu8wQkDmOBAhqkA6oapqWt6irBDYd7eu0XRGRAABiOIqTEUKhvFXrRvGybenpTA5pUFGH1OsHLuu261BoB6jqUZBAgAaxC4RZFaWcvrYRrmpW-7AZWkG9BC8GLLiGI4Y0hGxomkKFlR9HlGFrGzvQXGbroAmie80mKfQKmaYBT76vpn6mZCFngZ0dn0HBrU0jiXm61ARHBfQR4RbB5QbYlnGrplu7CZphXEqVkAVaGjzbZCgBZNhSBaG7wqa8KEAQUqMuUeg0ExPxaY1hnfralbOu6lbbvR3nLcmx9SugHRGVABalu20A1tizb2G2kBdv2w7juxi7nfx+73aUZ7XqB4x1e+xm-p1oGtH1sHIc+A1Ye882QHzkKkTCf30CX0qTslkBpY7t3HpJz3Kaa1XapTrXh4B0eyvHjmuZExwzZWhf0BI4EV7nIF19bqX29lzu95ARWh9qZwxPoPNOIBmaXzZhPY26QxAP35kjIWcE36wSOI0L+W8f6u3lvvcmQCaZ+z6mjMGAAlNgrs5Dh1kIVcggR8gxxoHHRcidk5gO1hfVm19Dbrhsvfby7UQCZx6qAHOYMAAqDJwqGAgB5POAsC4Mk-pvbev9d6z0fgokKPFChv1CkwGQuhMBxQAMpxmUOFNgw1wpBxDnVTAyinZ4zUbggBB9lZHyLutWuwVeqNwOitOmqceqGBAL0IhG8wZNWMYEEG-9Y7x1QKwryQA).

### 1. Can I use a different data-layout?

Right now, each point is an object

```json
{
    "pitch": -0.006149084584096612,
    "roll": 0.0007914191778949736,
    "speed": 4.747345444390669,
    "time": 0.519741,
    "x": -0.01731604791076788,
    "y": 0.020068310429957575,
    "yaw": 0.0038123065311157552,
    "z": -0.016005977140476142
}
```

With many data-points, this is a lot of memory just for repeating column names. Much better would be to have the data in the form

```json
{
    "time": [t1, t2, t3, ...],
    "x": [...],
    ...
}
```

but vega's "row first" representation doesn't allow for that. I already asked on Slack where someone suggested to use `Fold` and `Pivot`, but I'm not sure how to implement this. Is it possible to use data that are stored as arrays? I'm creating the data myself from a C++ program and I'm free to export a different representation easily. The only question is how do I make vega-lite understand?

### 2. Layers and legends.

If I had time-series data with an "indicator column", I could create plots that combine several graphs easily. Unfortunately, I don't have that and the only solution I found is to use layers. With this, I have to set the colours for different graphs explicitly (instead of using schemes) and I don't get a legend.

If layers are really to only option here to combine, e.g. x,y,z into one "Movement" plot, how can I get a legend for this plot that tells me red -> x, green -> y, and blue -> z?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is "yes" to both of your questions.

The key to the first question is to pass the data in a dense format and use the [Flatten Transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/flatten.html) to expand it.

The key to the second question is to use a [Fold Transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/fold.html) to turn multiple columns into an indicator plus a value.

Here is a demonstration of this for a single chart ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUUAlgLYZ4CMANAEyUDMlALALqUgAeeArE5T9axABPPLQa0WbAF4UalKgAZmAXxVsoAJwgA7LADMA9huJ5QelNCgZteEEVIg2nNiOkg1ZgyjC3nwxyAyghA4cLggAMZeaMQ2bMjoZCqCxBAaANbwICiE2mRs1lFguQDm8KCcCCB6hBjeWfb5dkIADmRwIACOaDpEMESIZMou5dW19R0JmAFQre1dPdp90ISDIMORXkajNXU+HVHosTNzWdoGxLmo68rKQA)):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "time": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "x": [5, 4, 5, 2],
        "y": [2, 3, 2, 4],
        "z": [1, 2, 1, 0]
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"flatten": ["time", "x", "y", "z"]},
    {"fold": ["x", "y", "z"], "as": ["column", "value"]}
  ],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "time", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "column", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is spot-on. I could easily adapt my code and make it work. Thank you.